# Mocking requests.post and requests.json decoder python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests

I'm creating a test suite for my module that uses the requests library quite a bit. However, I'm trying to mock several different return values for a specific request, and I'm having trouble doing so. Here is my code snippet that doesn't work:

```
class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('mypackage.mymodule.requests.post') 
    def test_change_nested_dict_function(self, mock_post):
        mock_post.return_value.status_code = 200
        mock_post.return_value.json = nested_dictionary
        modified_dict = mymodule.change_nested_dict()
        self.assertEqual(modified_dict['key1']['key2'][0]['key3'], 'replaced_value')
```

The function I am attempting to mock:

```
import requests

def change_nested_dict():
    uri = 'http://this_is_the_endpoint/I/am/hitting'
    payload = {'param1': 'foo', 'param2': 'bar'}
    r = requests.post(uri, params=payload)

    # This function checks to make sure the response is giving the 
    # correct status code, hence why I need to mock the status code above
    raise_error_if_bad_status_code(r)

    dict_to_be_changed = r.json()

    def _internal_fxn_to_change_nested_value(dict):
        ''' This goes through the dict and finds the correct key to change the value. 
            This is the actual function I am trying to test above'''
        return changed_dict


    modified_dict = _internal_fxn_to_change_nested_value(dict_to_be_changed)

    return modified_dict
```

I know a simple way of doing this would be to not have a nested function, but I am only showing you part of the entire function's code. Trust me, the nested function is necessary and I really do not want to change that part of it.

My issue is, I don't understand how to mock requests.post and then set the return value for both the status code and the internal json decoder. I also can't seem to find a way around this issue since I can't seem to patch the internal function either, which also would solve this problem. Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: there is no need to mock func `_internal_fxn_to_change_nested_value`, I did not see any args for this function in your test, the answer given seems to be correct.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you `mock` a class each child method is set up as a new `MagicMock` that in turn needs to be configured. So in this case you need to set the `return_value` for `mock_post` to bring the child attribute into being, *and* one to actually return something, i.e:

```
mock_post.return_value.status_code.return_value = 200
mock_post.return_value.json.return_value = nested_dictionary
```

You can see this by looking at the type of everything:

```
print(type(mock_post))
print(type(mock_post.json))
```

In both cases the type is `<class 'unittest.mock.MagicMock'>`

Comment: I like this but 1 downside I found is that you have to call `.json` vs `.json()` on the `mock_post` where @SRC 's answer allows for the function call by setting the return value to a lambda.

Answer (score 48):

I bumped here and although I agree that possibly using special purpose libraries is a better solution, I ended up doing the following

```
from mock import patch, Mock

@patch('requests.post')
def test_something_awesome(mocked_post):
    mocked_post.return_value = Mock(status_code=201, json=lambda : {"data": {"id": "test"}})
```

This worked for me for both getting the `status_code` and the `json()` at the receiver end while doing the unit-test.

Wrote it here thinking that someone may find it helpful.

Comment: This is exactly what I want, simply and easy.

Answer (score 2):

Probably it is better for you to look at some specialized libraries for requests testing:

[responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses)

[requests-mock](https://github.com/openstack/requests-mock)

[requests-testing](https://github.com/a-pertsev/requests-testing)

They provide clean way to mock responses in unittests.

Comment: The second library is moved to  https://requests-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 1):

An alternate approach is to just create an actual Response object and then do a `configure_mock()` on the original mock.

```
from requests import Response

class MyTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('mypackage.mymodule.requests.post') 
    def test_change_nested_dict_function(self, mock_post):
        resp = Response()
        resp.status_code = 200
        resp.json = nested_dictionary
        mock_post.configure_mock(return_value=resp)
        ...
```